# T4 error on VS. Compiling transformation: 'Write' is not a member 

Tags: visual-studio-2008, t4

I'm trying to use a class within a T4 template in VS2008.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing...

```
<#@ template language="VB" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".vb" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Windows.Forms.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SQLClient" #>
<# Call (New SomeClass).Start()#>
<#+
Private Class SomeClass
    Public Sub Start()
    #>test<#+
    End Sub
End Class 
#>
```

When I run this template... I get the following error...

---

> Error 1   Compiling transformation: 'Write' is not a member of
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingF77BDE667ECAD297F587D3D651053846.
>   GeneratedTextTransformation.SomeClass'.   D:\Development\PrivateProjects\CodeGeneration\CodeGeneration\Generation\Common\test2.tt 16  1   CodeGeneration

**Can anyone tell my why this causes the error it does and more importantly how to negate it's effects?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code...

```
#>test<#+
```

... internally translates to...

```
Write("test");
```

Since my class does not have a 'Write' method, the compile fails.

The workaround is....

```
<#@ template language="VB" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".vb" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Windows.Forms.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SQLClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>

<# Call (New SomeClass(Me)).Start()#>

<#+
Private Class SomeClass
Private mOutput as TextTransformation
Public Sub New(Output as TextTransformation)
    mOutput = Output
End Sub 
Public Sub Write(SomeText as String)
    mOutput.Write(SomeText)
End Sub 
    Public Sub Start()
        #>test<#+
    End Sub
End Class 
#>
```

Which results in the write being passed to the parent class for processing.